# Passing output of a Python script that contains tabs as argument in bash

Tags: bash

a school assignment is graded by printing an output from a Python script and passing it on as an argument to a small c program. Unfortunately the output string from python contains a tab, and bash recognizes it as two strings instead of one. How can I make it recognize as one string? Note that I cannot make modifications to the C program.

a minimal example is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("Fail!");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Success!");
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./a.out $(python -c 'print "\'a\tb\'"')
Fail!
```

Comment: This is really a bash-only question; it has nothing to do with python or C

Answer (score 2):

Quote the Python invocation so it's expanded as a single argument:

```
./a.out "$(python -c 'print "a\tb"')"
```

The `$()` wrapping avoids any confusion between the inner and outer double-quotes, so this is processed as you hoped.